# PHP mail() headers

Tags: php, email, header

I have the following headers that I want to pass to the `mail()` function:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$sender_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject:".$subject."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

$headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

$headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

$headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
$headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
$headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
$headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
$headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--"; 

$sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Since I don't require the user to provide an e-mail address, can i exclude the "From" and Reply-To" fields and let the server auto-complete those values or would this action result in a malformed headers?

Comment: crazy idea, test it and see

Comment: Why are you putting all the multipart sections in the headers? They should be in the message.

Comment: Thanks for no help :|  @Barmar: I need to send an attachment with the mail and this is what I found that I can understand. Besides, that wasn't the question.

Comment: And my comment wasn't an answer. Your attitude towards my attempt to be helpful makes me almost want to delete my real answer.

Comment: No attitude, but really, that wasn't relevant here. If you think there's something wrong in how I've formatted the headers then explain, otherwise...

Comment: Everything starting with `"--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";` should be in `$message`, not `$headers`.

Comment: So the message is just a long string that i used `htlmentities()` to extract it from a textarea. Can i just remove those boundaries? I only need to send a subject, a message and an attachment file, can you provide a better format then please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server will automatically fill in the `From` line. Depending on the OS, it either gets the default `From` header from `php.ini` or from the username that runs PHP (e.g. `www-user@yourdomain.com`).

By default there's no `Reply-to`, so replies are sent to the `From` address. This header is only needed when you want replies to go to a different address, so in your case there's no need for it.

If no replies are wanted you could let it default, but a common approach is to put an address like `NoReply@yourdomain.com` in the `From` line. This way, if they do reply, they'll get a bounce message saying that the account doesn't exist.

You're also putting the message body into `$headers`, which isn't right. It's working because you also put a blank line before them -- that's treated as the separator between the headers and the message, so everything after that is actually sent in the body. But you shouldn't depend on this, so those lines should be sent as the `message` argument in `mail()`.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: NoReply@yourdomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject:".$subject."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";

$body= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";

$body .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

$body .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
$body .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
$body .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
$body .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
$body .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
$body .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--"; 

$sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

There also seems to be no reason for `multipart/alternative` in the first body section, since you're not sending multiple versions of `$message`.

Comment: So I can just safely exclude both?

Comment: Ok, thank you. So how should the boundaries look like?

Comment: One last thing, is `@mail(...)` correct, does the use of `@` have any meaning here? I'm really a PHP newbie.

Comment: `@` tells PHP not to display errors or warnings if there's a problem detected by the function. It's usually a bad idea unless you have a good reason for suppressing errors.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So I can use just `mail()` instead.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, if I put the file attachment in the `$body` won't the file base64 string just be displayed allong with the message instead of making it downloadable for the mail recipient?

Comment: No. The header `Content-type: multipart/mixed` tells it that the body contains an attachment, and it parses that using the given boundary.

Comment: The point is that you WERE putting it in the body. `\r\n\r\n` ends the headers and starts the message body.

Comment: So the boundary1 and boundary2 will make sure the file won't be part of the message?

Comment: Ok, sorry for asking so many questions. I just want to make sure only the message string will be displayed in the mail body.

Comment: Also, should I remove `$body .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";`?

Comment: Yes, you should, since you're not providing any other alternatives. That's used when you're sending both plain text and HTML, so the mail client can let the user choose which to view. Remember to remove the `boundary2` lines from the body itself, too.

Comment: And the `"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\n";` line as well? I think that will be displayed too, right?

Comment: That line should go after `boundary1`, to tell the type of that part of the `multipart/mixed` body.

Comment: Each boundary is followed by a header that describes that section of the message. These internal headers are not displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Like I suspected, the base64 string along with the file description appear in the mail body instead as a attachment. The line `"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n\r\n";` also appears in the mail before the message, what could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you send me an example at barmar@alum.mit.edu?

Comment: I've sent you an email.